# Access 2010 Query add text to end of existing text if condition is met

Tags: sql-update, ms-access-2010

I have a column of data, diagnosis codes to be exact. the problem is that when the data is imported it turns 111.0 into 111 (or any whole number). I am wondering if there is an update query I can run that will add the ".0" to the end of any value that is 3 characters long. I had a problem of it stripping a value from 008.45 to 8.45 but I figured that part out using:

UPDATE Master SET DIAGNOSIS01 = LEFT("00", 3-LEN(DIAGNOSIS01)) + DIAGNOSIS01
WHERE LEN(DIAGNOSIS01)<3 AND Len(DIAGNOSIS01)>0;

I got that from here on stackoverflow. Is there a variation of this update query I can use to add to the right if it's only 3 digits?

Additional info... formats of the values in this column include xxx.x or xxx.xx with x being a number

When it comes to sql I am very new so please treat me like I'm 3... ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Master 
SET Master.DIAGNOSIS01 = IIf(Len([Master].[DIAGNOSIS01])=3,[Master].[DIAGNOSIS01] & ".0",[Master].[DIAGNOSIS01]);